# How to customize angular application's work flow so it would run from login page before goes to app module

Tags: node.js, angular, ant-design-pro

I am new to Angular. In my application, app module is set as the bootstrap module in the main.ts, so the app would run from my app.html. However, I'd like to add a welcome page so that user would login from there before they could access the app.

Here is my main.ts:

```
if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

My application currently runs from AppModule, but I'd like the application starts from index.html before user login.

Hope someone would kindly help here.

Comment: Use a route guard. https://angular.io/guide/router#milestone-5-route-guards

Comment: Thanks @nullptr.t for pointing that out, apart from authentication pages, is it possible to create a specific page that do not use the bootstrap template?

Comment: You can write your auth/login logic straight into the index.html (either with inline javascript or side load another script) and just prevent ```<app-root>``` from loading unless a certain condition has been met. Is there any particular reason you need to do this? You can also implement server side authentication such as:
https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/configuring-http-basic-authentication/
or
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/authentication/windowsauthentication/
But this will prevent any resources from loading.

Comment: @nullptr.t thanks, that solves my question!

Comment: @HazelWang could you give us more details of why you want to have a login page separately from your app?